# Login to Flickr account knowing only my account

Tags: flickr

I want to access my Flickr account. I know the account name, but not the email associated with it. I tried a couple of emails but Flickr doesn't recognize them.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you forget your login ID, you can find it using the [Sign-in Helper](https://login.yahoo.com/account/challenge/username?authMechanism=secondary&yid=&done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F&s=QQ--&c=GAbESwr.2bJXO1LPfc5j96iRm7AEwJtgLYDQKe_h4tmqZEuC98OwkbSG1ZEwAjbGYwHYFizSDldaAvHyk1KOY_WbwFWwSLq_Wnfi7KjuAqfaTACVg7YXJ6WnJ7w8hqb4p71IhtMD2UNkKdb3V_H_sQ2.U8TeRd8LHA7FUTo771Wguq4eB4z43o1nOSt39bgZQZjxMRwmv1y5G0p2fWbu2KjoRNK.Waah0WI-~A) or [Beam Me Up tool](https://www.flickr.com/beammeup?ytcheck=1&new_session=1).

If you have login issue check the [Official Thread](https://www.flickr.com/help/forum/en-us/72157668446997150/).

[Find your Flickr login ID](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN24007.html).

Comment: The links you provide require an email or phone number. All I have is my login id.

Comment: Use the second link and enter all the emails one by one to check if that is associated with Flickr or not.

Comment: As I said in the question, I tried entering emails.